# Web Service Windows Phone 7 (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to consume this http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl web service async on windows phone . My code is this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.InfoSoapTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.InfoSoapTypeClient();

        client.AllCardsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.AllCardsCompletedEventArgs>(GetAllPlayers);

        client.AllCardsAsync(true);

    }

    private void GetAllPlayers(object sender, ServiceReference1.AllCardsCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        textBlock1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

I 've read many similar anwers for similar questions but none for windows phone. The error that I am getting back is: "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Web service looks to consuming fine outside the project. When you tap on link you will see nothing but if you retype the link you will get the wsdl document.

Comment: sorry bro , I think you can't use wso protocol web service in windows phone 7. But, I'm looking at this. If I find anything I'll tell you.

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to consume from windows phone 8?

Comment: I haven't been in windows phone 8 seas yet, so I don't have a clue. I think you  only can know after you tried once.

Comment: this may or may not be true, but the problem may lay in the picture which comes when we first open the `.wsdl` page. When I try to read it's contents it just read Øá↨¿5-like characters. But when I try to read another service(.wsdl) it reads xml correctly. So if that picture will stay there, you may not reach the contents. But as I said, it may not be true.

Comment: well it says this when I try to build project: ` Warning Custom tool warning: Endpoint 'InfoSoap12' at address 'http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso' is not compatible with Silverlight 3. Skipping... `

Comment: nah, it wasn't true. Sorry bro, but it really doesn't support wso.I hope you can find a solution in another way.

Comment: Why don't you try WP8 to find out if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

"(405) Method Not Allowed" means your client is using a HTTP method that server does not expect (for example you're trying to do GET whereas server expects a POST). T

Try capturing http traffic with [fiddler](https://www.google.pl/#q=fiddler&safe=off) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and inspect the HTTP request that the app is sending and server's response. Compare them to a proper request/response pair that you get when consuming this service otuside of WP7 (you can use [WCFTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this).

Another way of attacking this would be to compare the proxy (client) classes that are generated when adding WebService reference in your WP7 app and in a standard Console App. Maybe the proxy on WP7 has some incorrect method signatures?

One more thing: when testing this service with WCFTestClient, I got an error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

So make sure the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` is set properly.